# Ошибка с сессиями в php

Tags: php, сессия

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но к сожалению сам не смог найти решения

Когда я писал авторизацию на сайте, я прописал session_start(); в этом же файле чтобы проверить как работает, потом я решил запустить начало сессии в файле с подключением в БД, т.к он подключается почти везде, из-за этого случился баг.

Баг заключается в том что теперь появляется ошибка которая гласит о том, что нельзя запустить сессию еще раз, т.к она уже запущена, я пытался удалить ее через unset(), и session_destroy(); но при вызове второй функции появляется еще одна ошибка, в ней сказано что нельзя удалить то, чего и так нету

Вот уже сижу и думаю как это решить[image: Без session_destroy();]

[image: С session_destroy();]

P.S На первом скрине написано что ошибка на 5 строке, но это не так, на самом деле на 3

Comment: Замените скриншоты на код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед стартом сессии проверяйте существование её идентификатора - если его нет, стартуйте сессию. Т.е., записывайте старт таким способом:

```
session_id() ?: session_start();
```

Comment: Нужно найти источник проблемы и устранить ее, а не замаскировать. У человека дважды инклудится файл в котором создается подключение к БД, а вы предлагаете проверять наличие сессии

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас сессия стартует только в одном файле и появляется такая ошибка, это значит, что вы подключаете этот файл более одного раза. С учетом того, что при подключении этого файла создается глобальный объект подключения к БД - проблема может очень сильно аукнутся.

Решение проблемы - подключать этот файл только один раз. Т.е. вместо `include`/`require` писать `require_once db.php`